# Angular authentication using Passport for Ionic App

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, mean-stack

I've built an API for my web app, which is built using MEAN stack.
Now I am trying to use this API on mobile client side which is built using Ionic Framework.
I'm using this code to perform an $http call to API:

```
    $http.post(ServerIP+'/login', {username: $scope.credentials.username, password: $scope.credentials.password}).success(function(response) {
        $scope.authentication.user = response;
        $location.path('/');
    }).error(function(response) {
        $scope.error = response.message;
    });
```

It gets a valid response with user object, but if I try to get some info from protected parts of an API it doesn't work and auth is being reset.

On web app, I use the same code and everything works fine.
This issue happens only on Ionic app.
I've set the CORS like that:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,  Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');

 // intercept OPTIONS method
 if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
   res.sendStatus(200);
 }
 else {
   next();
 }
});
```

Please, help me!

Comment: are you generating and using tokens or some strategy to match req?

Comment: Are you setting withCredentials = true globaly?

Comment: I am using passport-local-mongoose as a Local Strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by adding Token-Based Authentication.

Here's the article which shows how to do that: https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/

Sample of my "login" route:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res, next){
    if (req.user) {
        var token = jwt.sign(req.user, secret, {expireInMinutes: 60*24*7});
        res.json(token);
    };
});
```

For getting user object on protected routes, I'm using `expressJwt({secret: secret})` middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in your angular config:

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
});
```

Comment: I've tried already, but it doesn't seem to work. 
In the console I get this message:
"A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Comment: to solve the "wildcard" error you have to specify the url from you want to access like:
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://myfrontendapp.com');

but you are in Ionic and I think you don't have a domain (I'm not sure), check this blog may can help

http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Comment: I solved my problem by using jsonwebtoken and express-jwt. It seems that the best way was simply to make it Token-based